# MongoDB query with $near, $lte, and $gt

Tags: mongodb, performance, nosql

I'm trying to run the following query on a collection of events to find events that are a) near a location, and b) are taking place at a certain time:

```
db.events.find({
"location.geocode.geometry.location": {
    "$near": [-79.5181416,43.7181557]
},
"eventDates.start": {
    "$lte": ISODate("2015-12-19T00:00:00.000Z")
},
"eventDates.end": {
    "$gt": ISODate("2015-12-19T00:00:00.000Z")
}
```

});

Unfortunately this query takes 300000ms. Running the same query without the eventDates.end rule runs in about 300ms.

I have a 2d index as required by $near on location. I also have indexes for both eventDates.start and eventDates.end.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using the [query analysis tools](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/measure-index-use/), to see which (if any) indexes are being used when the query is run? See [db.collection.explain()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/#explain-method-executionstats) in the MongoDB docs.

Comment: I'm bit confused from your query. You are searching for something which is less than equals and also greater than same date?

Comment: Try db.find([yourQuery]).explain("executionStats") - if you can't do anything with the result yourself, post it here.